# Vaadin ListSelect с двумя заголовками

Tags: java, vaadin

Использую vaadin ListSelect для отображения объектов класса. Хочу добавить к названию каждого пункта ListSelect-а не только title, но id.

```
ListSelect select = new ListSelect("Templates", templatesContainer);
select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("title");
//select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("id"); нужно что-то вроде add, а не set
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

```
select.setItemCaption("id", "Title");
```